# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (python 2)

Tags: python

program to check if word starts & ends with same letter

```
def match_letter():
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        if len(word) >=2 and word[0] == word[-1]:
            count = count + 1
    return count

def main():
    words = []
    words_list = raw_input('Enter Words: ')
    words_list = words_list().split()
    for word in words_list:
        words.append(word)

    count = match_letter()
    print 'letter matched %d ' %count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this is my python code, giving an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python 2.7\same_letter.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python 2.7\same_letter.py", line 13, in main
    words_list = words_list().split()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

i am very thankful if anyone can help me..

Comment: Please add more info! Explain what the code does, what it is that you want it to do, besides the error.

Comment: this code checks if words in list starts and ends with same letter or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx Cyber.. It works for me.
this code works for me exactly as i want

```
def match_letter(words):
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        if len(word) >=2 and word[0] == word[-1]:
            count = count + 1
    return count

def main():
    words = raw_input('Enter Words: ').split()
    count = match_letter(words)
    print 'letter matched %d ' %count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

This line has an extra parentheses

```
words_list = words_list().split()
```

It could just be

```
words_list = words_list.split()
```

In fact, you have a number of extraneous steps, your code block

```
words = []
words_list = raw_input('Enter Words: ')
words_list = words_list().split()
for word in words_list:
    words.append(word)
```

Could be reduced to:

```
words = raw_input('Enter Words: ').split()
```

And if I understand your question, I would solve this using slicing

```
def same_back_and_front(s):
    return s[0] == s[-1]   # first letter equals last letter

>>> words = ['hello', 'test', 'yay', 'nope']
>>> [word for word in words if same_back_and_front(word)]
['test', 'yay']
```